# No sound with headphones in Linuxmint 19.1

Tags: linux-mint, audio, jack

There is not sound anymore in my headphones (jack connection) even though it used to work.

- During my last session, I did quite a lot of tweaks on my
  installation, so far, here is what I could retrieve:

  - `sudo apt install qt5ct qt4-qtconfig libqt5svg5 kvantum`
  - Updates with the update manager (including upgrading to Linux kernel 4.15.0.46.48)
- Since then, I have rebooted and that is when I noticed sound was gone.
- Headphones seems to be detected when plugged (Headphones built-in audio shows up in the Device section of the Audio configuration GUI
  when I plug it)
- The headphones work (tested elsewhere)
- I've tried booting on the previous kernel and removing the newly installed one (current situation: I'm on 4.15.0.45 now), and I still
  have no sound.

This is all beyond my knowledge, and my researches have led me nowhere.

How can I troubleshoot such issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been given the answer on the LinuxMint forum:

Add to manually reload Alsa `sudo alsa force-reload`

It sounds like a strange solution as I would assume that rebooting would reload modules anyway. But it didn't apparently, and this solution fixed the issue durably.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, unplug the headphones. Restart. Mint often starts with device busy on first start. A restart without device plugged in usually frees it up.
To verify this state, close all programs. speaker-test -Dplug:front -c2 -l5 -twav into terminal. If you hear sound, other steps are needed. If output = -16,Device or resource busy, restart with headphones unplugged should fix. This solution is only for those using front headphone jack mini plug